# Use Random Value for Class Java and print it on Main

Tags: java, variables, random, static, program-entry-point

I need to use random values for the variables `agentPosX` and `agentPosY`, and I need to print them to see which value are they getting.

The code is very long, but the lines where I need help are 52, 53, and 322.

I used `static`, but I don't think it is right.

Thanks

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


public class WumpusWorld {
public static final int PIT_FLAG        = 1;
public static final int WUMPUS_FLAG     = 2;
public static final int GOLD_FLAG       = 4;
public static final int BREEZE_FLAG     = 8;
public static final int STENCH_FLAG     = 16;
public static final int GLITTER_FLAG    = 32;
public static final int BUMP_FLAG       = 64;
public static final int SCREAM_FLAG     = 128;

private static final int FACING_NORT    = 1;
private static final int FACING_EAST    = 2;
private static final int FACING_WEST    = 3;
private static final int FACING_SOUTH   = 4;

/*
 * Actions
 */
public static final int GO_FORWARD      = 1;
public static final int TURN_LEFT       = 2;
public static final int TURN_RIGHT      = 3;
public static final int GRAB            = 4;
public static final int SHOOT           = 5;
public static final int CLIMB           = 6;

public static final String STR_GO_FORWARD   = "Avanzar";
public static final String STR_TURN_LEFT    = "Izquierda";
public static final String STR_TURN_RIGHT   = "Derecha";
public static final String STR_GRAB         = "Agarrar";
public static final String STR_SHOOT        = "Disparar";
public static final String STR_CLIMB        = "Escalar";
//matriz random

/*
 * Perceptions
 */
private int     perceptions = 0;

public  double  actionCost  = 1.0;
public  double  outWithGold = 1000.0;
public  double  killCost    = 10000.0;

public  int     worldDimensionX;
public  int     worldDimensionY;
public  double  pitProbability;

public static  int  agentPosX   = (int)Math.random()*10;
public  static int  agentPosY   = (int)Math.random()*10;
private int     agentDir    = FACING_EAST;
private boolean agentSafe   = true;
private double  agentScore  = 0.0;
private boolean agentArrow  = true;
private boolean agentGold   = false;
private boolean agentOut    = false;

private int world[];

PrintStream out = System.out;
Scanner reader;



public static void main(String args[]) {
//WumpusWorld prin = new WumpusWorld(worldDimensionX,worldDimensionY, pitProbability, actionCost, outWithGold, killCost);
    int n = 100;
    if ( args.length == 1 ) {
        try {
            n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("SIMULATION_STARTED");
    System.out.println("gato: " + agentPosX + " gatoY: " + agentPosY);


    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        WumpusWorld world = new WumpusWorld(10, 
                            10, 
                            0.15,
                            1, 
                            1000, 
                            1000);

        System.out.println("EPISODE_STARTED");

        while ( world.isAgentOk() & !world.isAgentOut() ) {
            System.out.println( world.getPerceptions() );
            world.readAction();
        }
        System.out.println("EPISODE_ENDED, AGENT_SCORE=" + world.agentScore);
        String line = world.readLine();
        if ( !"START_SIMULATION_REQUEST".equals(line) ) break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Which line is 322? And what do you need help with?

Comment: Hi Elliot
System.out.println("gato: " + agentPosX + " gatoY: " + agentPosY);
i want to print the values that agentPosX and Y are getting from the random.
i used static on the variable but i keep getting 0 values for both, and if i dont use the static i cant print them
im sorry if this is a silly question but i cant get it to work.

Comment: The questions would be a lot clearer if you removed all of the excess lines, and includes what it is printing and what you expect it to be printing.  Giving line numbers does not help, as stackoverflow does not make it easy for us to see line numbers.

Comment: hi Chris, i erased all the extra lines

Comment: @user3816958, you can go a little further. The question can be reduced to just setting agentPosX, and then asking why it is always being set to zero.  And that you expect it to be any of values 1-9 (or perhaps 0-9, in which case the answer that i gave would change slightly).

Comment: The thing to remember here is that after you have an answer to your question, this page stays around as a record to help other people.  So making the question as clear as possible is really helpful to other people who may struggle with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is essentially what you have in your code.

```
    System.out.println( (int)Math.random()*10 );   // prints zero
```

The code above will always print zero.  Why?  Because you are rounding a decimal value that is < 1 to an int.  Which is always zero.   To see this more clearly, consider the following examples:

```
    double v = Math.random();

    System.out.println( v );             // prints a decimal < 1
    System.out.println( (int) (v*10) );  // prints a value between 1 and 9
    System.out.println( (int) v*10 );    // prints 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Casting the result of [`Math.random()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29) like that is too soon, you want the multiplication first -

```
public static int agentPosX = (int) (Math.random()*10);
public static int agentPosY = (int) (Math.random()*10);
```

I would suggest you use a [`Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html),

```
private static Random rand = new Random();
public static int agentPosX = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
public static int agentPosY = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
```